add initial position
I would like to enhance the visualization by adding the initial position of the beams in a more transparent style, possibly using dotted edges. Is it possible to implement this in Blender? I've attached my image and Blender file for reference.
Thank you very much for your help in advance.
Best regards,



Could you explain "adding the initial position of the beams in a more transparent style" ? Also, what do you call beams in your file ? For now, I have absolutely no idea what you are asking.

@Lutzi I want something similar to what I attached now. I did this one at powerpoint but is it possible to do at blender ?

You could simply do this in compositing with some transparency : have 2 scenes, combined them in compositing. Did you try something like that ? I would suggest rename your question to "Combine 2 images with transparency" or something like that.

or duplicate your object and give a semi-transparent material to the copy that stays flat?

What you suggests work. Thank you so much!

Duplicating all the beams and increasing transparency from material properties, then rendering the scene after adjusting the camera and lights, give the desired image with the initial position.
